# $scope.$on changes not reflected in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, rootscope

I'm doing a broadcast and on listening to the broadcast i'm trying to updated a variable on the scope that I wanted to display on the view, but the changes are not being reflected in the view immediately, until I click on the UI. Anyone know what should be done at this point, I don't want to use $apply. Here, please find my code.

```
rApp.factory('pService', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$sanitize', 

function ($http, $rootScope, $sanitize) {

 var pService = {};

 //Some other code

 pService.Update=function(status)
 {
   if(status.LastItemId!=undefined)
   {
     pService.disItemId = status.LastItemId;
     $rootScope.$broadcast('updated',pService.disItemId);    
   }
 }

 //Some other code

return pService;

});


rApp.controller('dController', ['$scope','$rootScope' 'pService' ,dController]);

function dController($scope,$rootScope, pService) {

$rootScope.$on('updated',function (event, data) {
            $scope.lastItemId = data; // I want to display the lastItemId on UI
    })
});
```

Comment: You are missing event name. `$scope.$on('updated', function...` closing for typo

Comment: Another one.. where is `dispenseController` ? Also check for syntax error. you seem to have got that too..

Answer (score 0):

What triggers the event being sent, i.e. where does your service's `update()` method get called?  You may need to use apply to trigger a digest cycle if it is called from outside angular.  I see from the comment you are using SignalR, that will not create a digest cycle to update bindings in angular.  Try wrapping your call in an apply like this:

```
$rootScope.$apply(function(scope) {
    service.Update();
});
```

You also don't need to use `$rootScope.on()`, you can just use `$scope.on()`.  Broadcasts on the root scope will go down to all child scopes.  If the message isn't used elsewhere, you can use `$rootScope.emit()` which bubbles upward and won't go down through all your child scopes.

Comment: do you mean $broadcast ? if that is the case it is in my service which is above. In fact everything is angular

Comment: Update() method will be called by a different method in the service, which will then update the variables.

Comment: 'by a different method in the service' - when is THAT method called?  There has to be something that initiates that call, whether it is a user clicking a button, a timer, or the return from an ajax call.  If any of these are initiated from outside angular, a digest cycle will not be triggered and your code will not be executed.

Comment: it will be triggered by a message from signalR

Comment: ah, try wrapping the call to your service in an apply

Answer (score 0):

Ideally Services are used for sharing common methods in different controllers. It's good to return `this`. Also, if you need to return the value to controller, instead using events why don't you simply return the value from a service public method and access the value in controller. Also, it's the controllers' work to initiate or call services' method and update corresponding scopes. Firing event from a service to notify controller is similar to what `firing events from one controller to other`. Services are not made for that purpose. See my code for reference.

**DEMO - http://plnkr.co/edit/Co7ka0sZKZgYk5Oz88Np?p=preview**

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'pService', function ($scope, $rootScope, pService) {
  $scope.name = 'softvar';
  $scope.itemId = pService.Update({LastItemId: 4})

}]);

app.factory('pService', [ '$rootScope', function ( $rootScope) {

 this.pService = {};

 //Some other code

 this.Update= function(status) {
   if (status.LastItemId) {
     this.pService.disItemId = status.LastItemId;
     console.log(this.pService.disItemId)
     return this.pService.disItemId;    
   }
 }

  //Some other code
  return this;

}]);
```

**HTML**:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>ItemId is:  {{itemId}}!</h1>
</body>
```

### UPDATE:

**DEMO - http://plnkr.co/edit/Co7ka0sZKZgYk5Oz88Np?p=preview**

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'pService', function ($scope, $rootScope, pService) {
  $scope.name = 'softvar';

  $scope.$on('serviceUpdated', function (ev, data) {
    $scope.itemId = data;
  });

  pService.Update({LastItemId: 4});

}]);

app.factory('pService', [ '$rootScope', function ( $rootScope) {

 this.pService = {};

 //Some other code

 this.Update= function(status) {
   if (status.LastItemId) {
     this.pService.disItemId = status.LastItemId;
     console.log(this.pService.disItemId)
     $rootScope.$broadcast('serviceUpdated', this.pService.disItemId);   
   }
 }

  //Some other code
  return this;

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but part of my problem here is that my controller doesn't know when the value in the service is changed. I need to trigger that change from service to the controller.

Comment: I understand. Please see my updated answer. hope it answers your question well.

Comment: myController is not the one actually triggering the update in my service.